# Can I think of a field as a distributive category?

Tags: field-theory, category-theory

My understanding is that a field $(k, +, \times)$ is a set $k$ with abelian group structures $(k, 0, +)$ and $(k \setminus \{0\}, 1, \times)$ such that multiplication distributes over addition.

Can this be generalized to the categorical setting?
For example, if we adjoin to some category $\mathcal{C}$ a coproduct and product structures $(\mathcal{C}, \mathbb{0}, +)$ and $(\mathcal{C}, \mathbb{1}, \times)$ such that products distribute over coproducts, is this an analogue of a field?

A problem I see is that multiplication with 0 doesn't have an inverse, which I'm not sure how to talk about in a categorical setting.

**TLDR;** How can I think of fields in terms of category theory?

Comment: Categories generally don't have inverses with respect to product or coproduct, and one runs into trouble when trying to adjoin them, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100158/negative-objects-in-categories). I think the correct underlying structure is called a [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring).

Comment: A one-object $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched category is essentially a *ring*, but, as pregunton states, dealing with inverses leads to issues.